# Class Hierarchy Compiling Error in Java

Tags: java, hierarchy, bluej

It's my first time posting here on Stack Overflow, but I'm having trouble with an early step of a project I am working on (written in Java) and am looking for guidance. I've searched the forums, but am still having a difficult time understanding the error I'm making.

I'm creating a juvenile email-like system and, more specifically, working on class hierarchy and inheritance. My superclass is **Attachments** and a subclass of this is **ContainsDescription**.

When compiling, the error is occurring in the constructor of the **ContainsDescription** subclass. The error reads, "Actual and formal argument lists differ in length," which I don't quite know how to interpret. My code reads as follows:

```
public class Attachments
{
    private String filename;
    private int size;

    public Attachments(String filename, int kilobytes)
    {
        this.filename = filename;
        size = kilobytes;
    }

    public void preview()
    {
        System.out.println("Filename: " + filename + "\n");
        System.out.println("Size: " + size + " kB" + "\n");
    }
}

public class ContainsDescription extends Attachments
{
    private String description;

    public ContainsDescription(String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Some direction would be hugely appreciated, as much of my project consists of tasks like this one.

Comment: Your posted code has a syntax error; the constructor for `Attachments` isn't closed.

Comment: Thanks, I caught that almost immediately after posting and corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide a contructor in `ContainsDescription` that takes the parameters of your superclass.

You have to combine them:

```
public class ContainsDescription extends Attachments
{
    private String description;

    public ContainsDescription(String description, String filename, int kilobytes)
    {
        super(filename, kilobytes);
        this.description = description;          
    }
}
```

If you don't, it will not be able to construct the superclass.
If you really only want a constructor that takes a `Description` as argument you can provide default values:

```
public class ContainsDescription extends Attachments
{
    private String description;

    public ContainsDescription(String description)
    {
        super("", 0);
        this.description = description;          
    }
}
```

Comment: No; the problem is just that the existing constructor needs to construct the superclass.

Comment: @SLaks: edited it just now :) - Actually, my first code doesn't work indeed. One constructor wouldn't work. Changing now.

Comment: Thanks, Jeroen. The first one gave the same error, but the second worked. Didn't realize I had to construct the superclass in the subclass.

Answer (score 1):

What happening here is called constructor chaining in java , You can read more [here](http://java.about.com/od/c/g/constchaining.htm)

Since your parent class has a constructor with arguments , you need to explicitly invoke that.
Otherwise there will be an implicit invoke to the default constructor without arguments, In your case default constructor is not available. If you havent invoked it your code is same as

```
        public class ContainsDescription extends Attachments
    {
        private String description;

        public ContainsDescription(String description)
        {

            super();    //implicitly added by java. This will look for constructor withod argument in the super class
            this.description = description;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, @FreakyThommi. I'm in my programming infancy, so all information is useful.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the "Actual and formal argument lists differ in length" error simply because Java calls the default constructor of your superclass **without any parameters**.

However, your superclass doesn't have a constructor that accepts an empty parameter list. This would lead to the error of "Actual and formal argument lists differ in length", as its trying to construct with an empty parameter list, but all the constructors you have provided take in parameter lists of different sizes.

**There are two things you can do.**

1. **Either**, create another constructor of your superclass that accepts no parameters.
2. **Or**, make a call to super() in your inherited constructor, with the appropriate parameters.

This feature of OOP is essential in understanding the flexibility involved. This feature allows you to customize the state of the object defined by the super class before (or after) making the specific changes to such object once in the scope of the subclass. Such chaining of constructors among a chain of inheritances is a very powerful aspect of Java and OOP in general.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response @jab. Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Write a constructor

> public Attachments(){}

in your Attachments class so that your inheritance class can call the super class's constructor